# Modify location data for physics animated object

Tags: animation, physics, collision, rigidbody

I have a "coin" standing on a "table" which is being spun by the use of two projectiles, hitting opposite edges of the "coin," like the action fingers would have when spinning a real coin.  The "coin" plays out its animation, but the location parameters do not change.  This is a problem, not because I need to know the parameters, but rather because I want to change them and fix them.  I will be allowing all animation but translation through the X and Y axis.  I want the coin to spin and fall, but not travel around the table.  I cannot use python code, so please provide user friendly solutions.

Comment: Is this for video or perhaps a game where the projectiles are fired 'live' at the coin's edges?  If video, the spins can be initially started with physics then switched to keyframed animation to prevent the coin travelling around the table, however this would probably be more easily animated manually from the start. The fall when the spin slows enough, should be possible by switching back to physics.  I'll go off and try this.

Comment: Next day - adding to the above...  This worked very well. By baking the spin plus physics frames, the locations of the spinning coin could also be controlled in all axis' as desired, even to the point when it falls topsy-turvy and comes to rest, it does so exactly where you want it.  More info and Blend file available if required.